# Launch shell with inline assembly

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-smash

I am working on a school assignment and I am completely stumped. The professor and TA have been of no help as every answer they provide to any student is some variation of "keep looking, the answer is there." I am trying to create a shell using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char code[] =
"\x31\xc0"
"\x50"
"\x68""//sh"
"\x68""/bin"
"\x89\xe3"
"\x50"
"\x53"
"\x89\xe1"
"\x99"
"\xb0\x0b"
"\xcd\x80"
;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("running...\n");

char buf[sizeof(code)];
strcpy(buf, code);
((void(*)( ))buf)( );
}
```

I have tried to replace `code[]` with some other examples found online (including this site) as well as an example from an additional pdf the prof provided. None of these were useful. I used gdb to disassemble and attempted to construct my own `code[]` and that too failed. For what it's worth, I can say that in a normal user my application segfaults on the `((void(*)( ))buf)( );` line and just quits (no segfault notice) in a root user on the same line.

I have no idea where else to take this assignment and I can not work on any of the later buffer overflow tasks until I can understand this simple first step. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I have tried this on both OSX 10.8.2 and on a Ubuntu VM via VirtualBox. I'm assuming it won't work on OSX, but I was desperate. ha For Ubuntu, we were asked to do:

sudo #sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0

sudo apt-get install zsh
cd/bin
sudo rm sh
sudo ln -s /bin/zsh /bin/sh

Those commands should disable address space randomization, install zsh and link it to /bin/sh. I completed all of those tasks in the VM with no errors

Comment: Your system probably marks the pages in which your stack resides as non-executable. In a debugger you would see the segmentation fault at the time of a `call` instruction with the address of `buf` as the parameter. Does your assignment involve bypassing that protection?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I had intended to add that, but it was getting late! I have edited the question now with more information that should answer this question I believe.

Comment: Well, the problem you are facing has nothing to do with the code in question. Maybe you want to post the objective of your assignment?

Comment: @Michael There are multiple objectives later on, but initially I am just trying to launch a shell in terminal by calling this code above. The assembly commands in code[] came from a GDB disassemble of;          int main( ) {
   char *name[2];
   name[0] = ‘‘/bin/sh’’;
   name[1] = NULL;
   execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}

Comment: Well then, you must first find a suitable place to run your shellcode from. Read up on non-executable stack protection (and [execstack](http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack)), or get more creative (for instance, why even copy the shellcode?).

Comment: @michael would compiling without -fno-stack-protector resolve the stack protection issue? I could have sworn I tried that last night! I'm also going to try adding the -z execstack to my gcc command when I get back on this later

Comment: No, it would not. There is no stack smashing involved in the code you posted.

Comment: @Michael Ok, I wasn't 100% sure of its use. Stack smashing is one of the later tasks so I suppose that will come in handy soon enough.

Comment: This is what a did to disable NX flag on Linux using gcc: `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o your_executable your_source.c`

Comment: The "-z execstack" got it running. I apreciate your time @Michael. That's exactly what I was looking for, if you make an answer below I will approve it!

Answer (score 15):

Your code disassembles to something like this :

```
00000000  31C0              xor eax,eax
00000002  50                push eax
00000003  682F2F7368        push dword 0x68732f2f
00000008  682F62696E        push dword 0x6e69622f
0000000D  89E3              mov ebx,esp
0000000F  50                push eax
00000010  53                push ebx
00000011  89E1              mov ecx,esp
00000013  99                cdq
00000014  B00B              mov al,0xb
00000016  CD80              int 0x80
```

Courtesy of `ndisasm`. Let's go through these instructions step by step and analyse the stack frame on the way.

`xor eax,eax` zeroes out the `eax` register, since the XOR operation of an operand with itself will always yield zero as the result. `push eax` then pushes the value on the stack. Therefore, the stack currently looks more or less like this (offsets shown relative to the value of `esp` at the start of the code, `esp` means the stack cell that `esp` currently points to) :

```
       +----------+
     0 | 00000000 |
esp -4 | xxxxxxxx |
       +----------+
```

Next, we have two `push dword` instructions, which push some immediate value to the stack, which - after executing them - looks like this :

```
       +----------+
     0 | 00000000 |
    -4 | 68732f2f |
    -8 | 6e69622f |
esp -12| xxxxxxxx |
       +----------+
```

`esp` currently points at the last byte of the second immediate value that was pushed to the  stack. Let's try interpreting the pushed values as ASCII, in the order that they will be read from the stack if we start sequentially from the current value of `esp`. We get the byte sequence of `2f62696e2f2f7368`, which in ASCII is equal to `/bin//sh`. Plus, the sequence ends with a 0, so it is a valid C-string.

This is the main reason why the current value of `esp` is saved into the register `ebx`. It contains the path to the executable that will be run. The double slash is not a problem for the OS, since POSIX simply ignores multiple occurrences of slashes and treats them as one slash.

Next, we have the current values of `eax` and `ebx` pushed into the stack. We know that `eax` contains zero, and `ebx` contains a pointer to the C-string `"/bin//sh"`. The stack currently looks like this :

```
           +----------+
         0 | 00000000 |
        -4 | 68732f2f |
        -8 | 6e69622f |
    ebx -12| 00000000 |
        -16| (ebxVal) |
ecx esp -20| xxxxxxxx |
           +----------+
```

After pushing the values of the registers to the stack, the current pointer to `esp` is saved in `ecx`.

`cdq` is an instruction that performs a very neat trick in this case : it sign-extends the current value of `eax` into the `edx:eax` register pair. Therefore, in this case, it zeroes out the value in `edx`, since the sign extension of zero is zero. We could, of course, clear the value in `edx` with `xor edx, edx`, but that instruction is encoded with two bytes - and `cdq` only takes up one.

The next instruction puts the value `0xb` (11) into the low byte register of `eax`. Similarly as in the previous case, we could just do `mov eax, 0xb`, but that would lead to a 5-byte instruction, as immediates must be encoded as full 32-bit values.

`int 0x80` calls the system call invoker on Linux. It expects the number of the system call in `eax` (which now equals `0xb`, so the `sys_execve` function will be called), and additional arguments in `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `esi`, `edi`, and `ebp`.

Now, let's have a look at the prototype for that system call :

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

Therefore, the `filename` argument is placed in `ebx` - it points to `/bin//sh`. `argv`, placed in `ecx`, is an array of arguments for the executable which is to be executed and must be terminated with a `NULL` value. On the Intel architecture, `NULL` is equal to `0`, and `ecx` points to just that : a pointer to `/bin//sh`, and then a `NULL` value. `envp`, which is `NULL`, points to an array of environment values, which must be expressed as `char*` values of the form `key=value`.

The successful execution of `execve` results in the current process image replaced with the image of the pointed-to executable, executed with the arguments provided. In this case, `/bin/sh` will be executed (if it exists) with the argument of `/bin//sh`.

Michael was probably right as to why this doesn't work : recent Linux kernels mark the data pages as non-executable, and trying to execute them will result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: This was valuable knowledge that I'm sure will come in handy here shortly. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

did you try to compile your c program with the following gcc flags?

```
-fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

If your shellcode is error free then you can execute it with the

```
((void(*)( ))buf)( );
```

If you fail to include the the compilation flags you can bump into segment faults

Comment: `const char code[]` goes in the `.rodata` section, which is linked into the text segment.  It will be mapped in executable memory even if the stack and static read/write data aren't, in a normal Linux executable.